# Youtube won't play in Chrome on Elementary OS Juno

Tags: release-juno, google-chrome

I am running Elementary OS Juno and Youtube will not play within Chrome.  I press the play button but nothing plays.  If I run Epiphany, Youtube videos play fine.  I can only assume it has something to do with the Chrome configuration.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think I may be able to answer my own question.  I have the YouTube Flash Video Player extension installed.  If I change the video player from "Flash Player" to "HTML 5 Player" then videos play fine.